# How to filter string by regx in object c

Tags: objective-c

Assumed that there is a string

```
NSString *str = @"https://www.xxx.com?t=aaa&m=bbb&s=92,"
```

Now i want to get the value of t,m,s as below:

```
aaa,bbb,92
```

Who can tell me how to implement it in object c?

Comment: This is not a question about Objective-C.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try like this:-

```
    NSString *str1 = @"https://www.xxx.com?t=aaa&m=bbb&s=92,";
    NSMutableArray *arr1=[[str1 componentsSeparatedByString:@"="]mutableCopy];
    [arr1 removeObjectAtIndex:0];
    NSMutableArray *mutArray=[NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSString *str1 in arr1)
    {
        ([str1 length] >3)? [mutArray addObject:[str1 substringToIndex:3]] : [mutArray addObject:[str1 substringToIndex:2]];
    }
    NSLog(@"%@",[mutArray componentsJoinedByString:@","]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simple approach would be

```
NSString *str = @"https://www.xxx.com?t=aaa&m=bbb&s=92,";

NSArray * list = [str componentsSeparatedByCharactersInSet:[NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString:@"?=&,"]];


//Test result    
for (int i = 1; (i+1)<[list count];i = i +2)
{
    NSLog(@"%@ = %@",[list objectAtIndex:i],[list objectAtIndex:(i+1)]);
}
```